# ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model) inside a single app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Django 3.0, Python 3.7.5

Here is `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Owner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Ім`я', max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамілія', max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField('По-батькові', max_length=30)

class Address(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Власник')
    house = models.IntegerField('Будинок', default=0)
    street = models.CharField('Вулиця', max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField('Місто', max_length=30)
    region = models.CharField('Область', max_length=30)
    cantry = models.CharField('Країна', max_length=30)

class Car(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField('Номер', primary_key=True)
    date = models.CharField('Місто', max_length=30)
    brand = models.CharField('Марка', max_length=30)
    colors = models.CharField('Кольори', max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField('Стан', max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Власник')
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Адреса')

class Engine(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Машина')
    cylinders = models.CharField('Циліндри', max_length=30)
    fuel_injection = models.CharField('Вприскування пального', max_length=30)
    supercharger = models.CharField('Суперчарджер', max_length=30)
    catalytic = models.CharField('Каталізатор', max_length=30)
    automatic = models.CharField('Автоматичний', max_length=4)

class Performance(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, verbose_name='Машина')
    # car = models.ForeignKey('Машина', Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    acceleration = models.FloatField('0-100 kmph (сек)', default=0)
    max_speed = models.IntegerField('Максимальна швидкість', default=0)
    fuel_eff = models.FloatField('Витрата пального', default=0)
    pollution_class = models.CharField('Клас забруднення', max_length=8)
    base_price = models.IntegerField('Базова ціна', default=0)

class Type(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, verbose_name='Машина')
    # car = models.ForeignKey('Машина', Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body_type = models.CharField('Тип кузова', max_length=16)
    no_of_door = models.IntegerField('Кількість дверей', default=0)
    no_of_seats = models.IntegerField('Кількість сидіннь', default=0)
    engine_place = models.CharField('Місце мотору', max_length=2)
    drivetrain = models.CharField('Привід', max_length=16)

class Body(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, verbose_name='Машина')
    # car = models.ForeignKey('Машина', Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wheel_base = models.IntegerField('Колісна база', default=0)
    track_front = models.IntegerField('Передня колія', default=0)
    track_rear = models.IntegerField('Задня колія', default=0)
    length = models.IntegerField('Довжина', default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField('Ширина', default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField('Висота', default=0)
```

Here is created migration `0001_initial.py`

```
# Generated by Django 3.0 on 2019-12-15 08:59

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Address',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('house', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Будинок')),
                ('street', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Вулиця')),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Місто')),
                ('region', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Область')),
                ('cantry', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Країна')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Body',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('car', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, to='polls.Car', verbose_name='Машина')),
                ('wheel_base', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Колісна база')),
                ('track_front', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Передня колія')),
                ('track_rear', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Задня колія')),
                ('length', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Довжина')),
                ('width', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Ширина')),
                ('height', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Висота')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Car',
            fields=[
                ('number', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='Номер')),
                ('date', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Місто')),
                ('brand', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Марка')),
                ('colors', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Кольори')),
                ('state', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Стан')),
                ('address', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Address', verbose_name='Адреса')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Owner',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ім`я')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Фамілія')),
                ('surname', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='По-батькові')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Performance',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('car', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, to='polls.Car', verbose_name='Машина')),
                ('acceleration', models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='0-100 kmph (сек)')),
                ('max_speed', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Максимальна швидкість')),
                ('fuel_eff', models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Витрата пального')),
                ('pollution_class', models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Клас забруднення')),
                ('base_price', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Базова ціна')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Type',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('car', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, to='polls.Car', verbose_name='Машина')),
                ('body_type', models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Тип кузова')),
                ('no_of_door', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Кількість дверей')),
                ('no_of_seats', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Кількість сидіннь')),
                ('engine_place', models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name='Місце мотору')),
                ('drivetrain', models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Привід')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Engine',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('cylinders', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Циліндри')),
                ('fuel_injection', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Вприскування пального')),
                ('supercharger', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Суперчарджер')),
                ('catalytic', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Каталізатор')),
                ('automatic', models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Автоматичний')),
                ('car', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Car', verbose_name='Машина')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='car',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Owner', verbose_name='Власник'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='address',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Owner', verbose_name='Власник'),
        ),
    ]
```

And here is the `error`

```
(ENV) [b@l mysite]$ python manage.py migrate polls
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: polls
Running migrations:
  Applying polls.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 233, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 322, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 159, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 212, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 971, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 968, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 880, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 632, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 619, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/home/b/django/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'polls.Car' cannot be resolved
```

How does it cannot resolve related models inside of one app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that `migrations.CreateModel` migration for `Body` is present in migration file before `CreateModel` for `Car`, more specifically, that it has

`('car', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, to='polls.Car', verbose_name='Машина')),`

line in **`Body`** CreateModel **before** **`Car`** model was created.

This is probably because `car` field on `Body` has `parent_link=True`, which indicates that link should be made to parent model and thus this field will not be present on current (child) model and it is safe to include this field in migration where it is.

But in your case this is not child model, it is not inherited from any parent model, so using `parent_link=True` is not needed.

Best option is to **remove `parent_link=True`**, remove previously created migration file and re-create migrations.

Another option is to simply edit migration file and move CreateModel for `Body` after CreateModel for `Car`, but this is not recommended.